# Setting cache expiration inside htaccess for static resources

Tags: php, .htaccess, cache-control

I've added the FilesMatch branch below, inside my htaccess, but google pagespeed still complains about setting cache expirations. Is this code valid?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this pattern for most of my pages with good success. This i place under the mod_rewrite options. Hope this helps.

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. In HTML5, there's no need to specify a type attribute on the script tag (eg, type="text/javascript"). Does ExpiresByType text/javascript still catch it?

Comment: @ScottB I forgot about that. I still use type on my <script> so it hasn't slipped my mind. Hope someone more familiar can answer this for you. Found this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531994/specifing-expiration-date-for-static-files-caches[/link]. The question is very similar to yours. Hope that helps.